Power series and "substitution"
I was solving an exercise on real power series, and I was able to do it with intuition, without justifying formally all the passages. Now I would like to know why I can solve the exercise the way I did.
EXERCISE
Find the function series that has, as a sum, $f(x) = \arctan(x^2)$, using the geometric series.
SOLUTION
Since $\sum _{n=0} ^\infty t^n=\frac{1}{1-t}$, for $t \in (-1,1)$, I can substitute $t=-x^4$ and this yields $\sum _{n=0} ^\infty (-x^4)^n=\frac{1}{1+x^4}$ and this is true for $x \in (-1,1)$ thanks to this result. Then
$$2x\sum _{n=0} ^\infty (-x^4)^n = 2\sum _{n=0} ^\infty (-1)^n x^{4n+1} = \frac{2x}{1+x^4}$$
and this is also true for $x \in (-1,1)$ since multiplying for $2x$ outside the series clearly doesn't change the convergence interval.
Now we can integrate term by term the series and we obtain
$$\int 2\sum _{n=0} ^\infty (-1)^n x^{4n+1} = 2\sum _{n=0} ^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{4n+2}}{4n+2}$$
MY QUESTIONS
Now my questions are:

Can someone recommend a source for the result I linked, maybe a little bit more detailed?
When we integrate the series term by term, can we do it because the function series is obtained from a power series with a substitution and that "preserves" the properties of the power series, such as being integrable term by term in its interval of pointwise convergence? If yes, can someone link some sources for a result that says this? If no, it probably is integrable term by term because the solution is implicitly studying its uniform convergence, correct?
The exercise says that the we have to find a sum for $\arctan(x^2)$, but with the solution written above we're actually just doing it for $x \in (-1,1)$, correct?
Can someone provide some sources in general for when results on power series of type $\sum _n ^\infty a_n x^n$ (with $a_n$ being a sequence of real numbers) are also true for function series of type $\sum _n ^\infty a_n (f(x))^n$ with $f$ being a real function?


In this case, $f(x)$ is just a monomial, so the result of the substitution is still a power series. $$\sum {n=0} ^\infty (-1)^n x^{4n+1} = \sum{k=0}^\infty b_kx^k$$ where $$b_k=\begin{cases}(-1)^{(k-1)/4}&k \equiv 1\bmod 4\0&k \not\equiv 1\bmod 4\end{cases}$$

And concerning your first question, it is hard to see what more you could want. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n$ converges whenever $t \in (-1,1)$. It doesn't matter how you obtained the value $t$. The convergence is the same if you simply chose the value of $t$ directly, or chose a value for another variable $x$, then calculated $-x^4$ and used that value for $t$. That is all the substitution is doing. It is proclaiming a certain method for getting the value of $t$ to be used in series. So all that matters is the value of $t$ obtained is in $(-1,1)$.

And question 3 is for your instructor to decide, not some randos on the internet.

@PaulSinclair Regarding the observation that my series still is a power series, and question 1), thank you. So that means that, as long as I can bring a generic function series $\sum _{n=0} ^\infty f_n(x)$ in the form of a power series $\sum _{n=0} ^\infty a_n t^n$ with substitutions or "algebraic/re-writing tricks", I can study convergence in the variable $t$ using results on power series, correct? But it doesn't necessarily mean that I will be able to study it back in the variable $x$.

@PaulSinclair about question 3, I poorly worded it. The exercise I was given doesn't mention anything about which are the permitted values of $x$, but the solution of the exercise is the same I've written in the answer. Given that solution, we're actually studying a function series that has $\arctan(x)$ as a sum only for $x \in (-1,1)$ correct? Last, question 4 shouldn't be useful anymore if what I've written in the previous comment is true, correct?

On 3, power series have a definite radius of convergence. the solution will be for all points inside that radius. And it is not "algebraic/re-writing tricks" that make this a power series. That was just looking past the notation itself to what that notation means. When you have an expression that is adding up monomials, that expression is a power series, and all the results abot power series apply to it. For adding up arbitrary functions, you must be more cautious, but monomials are particularly well behaved.

@PaulSinclair ok thanks, but then I'm missing why you have to be "more cautious" with other functions. For example: suppose we have $\sum _{n=0} ^\infty \frac{1}{n}(arctan(x))^n$, shouldn't it be okay to reason in the exact same way? From wolfram alpha, it seems yes https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=convergence+of+series+1%2Fn+arctan%28x%29%5En. What are some examples of function $f(x)$ such that $\sum _{n=0} ^\infty (f(x))^n$ convergence cannot be studied as a power series in t with a subtitution $t=f(x)$
